# How to always open downloaded files in Outlook 2013

Tags: download, microsoft-outlook-2013, attachments, file-download

When I download an attachment in Outlook I always want to open it right away. But Outlook does not provide a link to the recently downloaded file for easy access, like chrome does. So in order to open it, I have to manually navigate to the download location to open it.

I want to streamline this process, so I can quickly read any file I download from Outlook.

Is it maybe possible to get Outlook to open downloaded files by default?

Comment: Do you mean downloading from a link or saving/opening an attachment?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really struggling to understand the question - can you try to re-word it?

Comment: Saving from attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook does not have the feature you described. You do have a couple options when [saving attachments](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/save-attachments-HA102785898.aspx).

1. Open the attachment, then if you choose to save it, do so from whatever program was used to view it.
2. Preview the attachment in the reading pane to decide if you want to save it. If so, choose to save attachment(s) within the message.